# Fastest MongoDB query for network data using indexing?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have a network collection myNetwork that looks like:

```
{ _id:, source: "Node1", target: "Node534"},
...
```

Let's say it's size 500K, but my network collections can be as large as 2M documents.

In one of my queries I have a array of nodes: myNodes = ["Node1", "Node14", "Node62", "Node144"] and I want to query the myNetwork collection and get all edges between the nodes in the array. Currently I do a find on myNetwork:

```
db.myNetwork.find({}).toArray(function(err, myNet){

   // iterate through myNet objects and only keep those that source or target is in myNodes.

})
```

How can I use indexing to optimize this query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add separate indexes on `source` and `target` and use an [`$in`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/in/#op._S_in) query instead of getting all docs:

```js
db.myNetwork.ensureIndex({source: 1})
db.myNetwork.ensureIndex({target: 1})

db.myNetwork.find({$or: [
    {source: {$in: myNodes}},
    {target: {$in: myNodes}}
]}).toArray(function(err, myNet) { ... });
```

Each `$or` clause can use its own index so both indexes will be used.